# camel getRoutes returns empty list, how to implement a route controller

Tags: apache-camel

i have an java based camel app (using guice). I want to separate start/ stop of all routes into a class "RouteControl" (no route should be aware of this central control).
At the moment all configured routes are autostart=false and RouteControl injects CamelContext and does this:

```
/**
 * Starts all routes found in context.
 */
public void startAll() {
    log.info("starting all routes.");
    for (Route route : context.getRoutes()) {
        String id = route.getId();
        try {
            log.info("starting route " + id);
            context.startRoute(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to start route " + id + " cause, ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

But this isn't working: if i call this after main.run() (it is not called, because run not returns) but if i call this before main.run context.getRoutes() is returning an empty list. But log says `Total 2 routes, of which 0 is started.`

So something is wrong, or is there a better way to implement such a central route control?

**Update** (Claus' answer is not working):

Now my code look like that:

```
/**
 * Starts all routes found in context.
 */
public void startAll() {
    log.info("starting all routes.");
    for (RouteDefinition route : ((ModelCamelContext) context).getRouteDefinitions()) {
        String id = route.getId();
        try {
            log.info("starting route " + id);
            context.startRoute(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to start route " + id + " cause, ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The loop is correct now - i see "starting route" fore each route but at the end the log states: `DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Total 2 routes, of which 0 is started.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRoutes` is the current routes in CamelContext, which means the current *running* routes. Use `getRouteDefinitions` to get all the defined routes (both running and not running) and you can then use that to start the routes. There is a `getRouteStatus` to know the state of the route whether its running or not.

Comment: In case you found this answer via Google in >= 2021 and using the Camel 3, the `getRouteDefinitions` moved to:
`ModelCamelContext modelCamelContext = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class); modelCamelContext.getRouteDefinitions();`